# Excel VBA Sorting not sorting all columns

Tags: vba, excel

My code is sorting the Column `A` Numerically correctly and also info tied to it in column `B-D` but not Columns `E-M` which are qty values. So when I add a Stock # the Description, supplier and Part # all sort with the Stock #, but not any qty values. They just stay in the same row. I have data that needs to stay with the sorted stock # until Column `X`.

```
Sub Sorting()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range

    Set sht = Sheet1
    Set StartCell = Range("A9")

    'Refresh UsedRange
      Worksheets("Order Summary").UsedRange

    'Find Last Row
    LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'Select Range
    sht.Range("A9:A" & LastRow).Select

    Range("A9:A" & LastRow).Sort _
      Key1:=Range("A9"), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Try 
Range("A9:X" & LastRow).Sort _
Key1:=Range("A9"), Header:=xlYes

Comment: I've tried that. it gives me a syntax error :(

Comment: You are not specifying the full range (columns A, B, C, D).  Change your line: "Range("A9:A" & LastRow).Sort _" which only covers column A  to "Range("A9:D" & LastRow).Sort _" which will cover A thru D

Comment: Also, I must disagree with you saying it is sorting columns C - D. Your code only sorts column A.  Maybe the code you posted is not current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Sorting()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A9")
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SetRange Range("A9:X500")
    ActiveSheet.Sort.Apply
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.